# Drupal Cache & Stylesheet Switch

Tags: drupal

I'm using a very simple Stylesheet Switch by php. It was fine all along but days ago I turn on Caching mode and now it only work for login user. If turn off Caching mode, it will work again for both user.

Basically the code looks like this

**In the page.php header**

```
  <?php
    if(isset($_COOKIE['style'])){
      $style=$_COOKIE['style'];
    } else {
      $style='green';
    }
  ?>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/css/<?php echo $style ?>.css">
```

**It switch by**

```
<a href="http://www.mydomain.com/switch.php?style=blue">Blue</a>
```

**In the switch.php**

```
<?php setcookie('style', $_GET['style'], time()+31536000);
header('Location:'.$HTTP_SERVER_VARS['HTTP_REFERER']);
?>
```

I did many research but couldn't find the right way. Please help if you can. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm, I don't see why you can't just use a client-side style switcher, as in http://www.alistapart.com/articles/alternate/. There are other methods of doing it purely client-side, but it seems a bit overkill to request an entire new page to switch styles.

Also, caching creates a static page to serve up in lieu of dynamically creating a new page for every hit, so the cached page is probably getting served up to whoever isn't getting the style switching.

Comment: Thank you very much for respond. I saw the article before. I didn't try it because I want user be able to switch it on the main menu instead of on a page. onclick="setActiveStyleSheet('') seems bit hard to implement on primary menu list. May be I should just give up my preference on this. You are right, client-side switcher might be my only option if I turn the Cache mode on.

Comment: +1 - Enabled caching will pretty much 'disable' any custom php code that would alter a page served for a specific URL, as the page will indeed be served as a 'static' version taken directly from the cache tables. So a client side solution would be the obvious workaround.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding/experience standard drupal caching is only for non-logged in users. There is at least one module that allows for authenticated user caching, but it's not in Core, authcache:
http://drupal.org/project/authcache

An old article that explains druapl caching techniques. Still has some good information in there: http://n0tablog.wordpress.com/2007/11/19/drupal-caching/